# Operational Semantics - Include SKIP, SEQUENCE and IF?

Tags: formal-languages, formal-methods, operational-semantics

I'm writing a paper for a programming languages workshop in which I have to describe the semantics of a new optimization for Java using Operational Semantics, small step style.

I have never used Operational Semantics before so I'm doubtful as whether to include in the paper some rules I'm using that are rather... let's say "common", such as the SKIP and the IF rules.

My programmer mindset tells me that perhaps there is some kind of "repository" of rules I can refer to by citing a paper or saying something *"the common SKIP and the common IF rules you all know"* in the paper

So the question is: **should I include all rules in my paper or there is a way a can refer to them by citing, etc.?**

Comment: I typically see these rules included, but the author usually points out that they are your "standard" varieties.

Comment: If they would be the standard ones, I wouldn't object if they are missing: in a PL conference everyone should know how these look like. If space is an issue, you could add these in the appendix: many values will allow you to submit an appendix, which the reviewers might or might not read, and will likely not get published if the paper is accepted. Even if a reviewer may ignore the appendix, many do look there if in doubt (at least I do). Double check whether your venue allows that, though.